# Rename a field in tree view and kanban view (odoo12)

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to rename a field  : "planned_revenue" in "crm.lead" model .

Here is the code:

//.py

```
class crm_revenue(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    new_field = fields.Char(string='New Name')
```

//.xml

```
<record id="crm_case_tree_view_oppor" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">crm.lead.tree.opportunity</field>
                <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                        <xpath expr="//tree[@string='Opportunities']//field[@name='planned_revenue']" position="inside">
                               <attribute name="string" >new_field</attribute>
                        </xpath>
                </field>
        </record>

  <record id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads" model="ir.ui.view">
                        <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.lead</field>
                        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
                        <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
                        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                             <xpath expr="//kanban//field[@name='planned_revenue']" position="inside">
                                   <attribute name="string" >new_field</attribute>
                             </xpath>

                        </field>

            </record>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Do you need to show `new_field` instead of `planned_revenue`?

Comment: @Kenly , yes. It work for a form view when create new opportunity , but doesn't work for kanban view , even adding a new field when trying this code :                                                      `<xpath expr="//kanban" position="inside">
                             <field name="currency_id" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>
                        </xpath>`

Comment: what you exactly meant by rename?you just need a different label for the field 'planned_revenue' or you need to replace the field with new field?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch this video for [View Inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20inherit%20view%20in%20odoo%2013&oq=how%20to%20inherit%20view%20in%20odoo%2013&aqs=chrome..69i57.8820j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_Yxt7XsX8Ad2K4-EPiN6XkAo16) and modify your changes through XPath on any tree/kanban view.
Only you have to use like,

```
<field name=”inherit_id” ref=”module_name.id_of_form_view”/>​​​
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating your expression, the first `planned_revenue` located is used.

The field `planned_revenue` is declared before the template tag to be used later inside the template.

You need to change your XPath expression to specify the field inside the template.

```
<record id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.lead.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_record_subtitle')]/t/field[@name='planned_revenue']" 
               position="">

        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer and you are welcome, to ask for clarification.